# NextJS 14 passing data with router.push from next/navigation

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use NextJS 14 and I want to pass an object to a page with router.push from next/navigation without using url directly.

Unfortunately I did not find how doing it with the new next/navigations hooks.

I tried this:

**page1**

```
router.push(
  `/restaurant/${params.uniqueValue}/checkout/order/${newOrder.data.orderNumber}`,
  {
    query: { test: "test" },
  }
);
```

**page2**

```
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  console.log(searchParams.test);
```

But the searchParams.test is undefined

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

// add a guard to make sure you have the right search param. for example

if (typeof params.uniqueValue !== 'string' || !params.uniqueValue) {
    redirect('/');
  }
// maybe check for newOrder.data.orderNumber as well
redirect(`/restaurant/${params.uniqueValue}/checkout/order/${newOrder.data.orderNumber}?test= "test"`)
```

Answer (score 0):

The new NextJS navigation can be pretty confusing, but the concept isn't that difficult to grasp.

You can learn about dynamic routing here: [NextJS Routing: Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes)

You are going to want to setup your actual page routes so lets say your order page is: */create/new-order/*

The code on this page.tsx (page1) would be:

```
router.push(`/create/new-order/${uniqueValue}/ref/${newOrder.data.orderNumber}`);
```

This would be on a successful submission, and once the submission is successful you will return the values you need like the ID from the order that was submitted - then use them in your router.push (you do not need the query).

Now it is important to setup your routes correctly because that is how you utilize the params feature.

Page2 Route: */create/new-order/[id]/ref/[orderNumber]/*

Now this route allows you to have any value for [id] and any value for [orderNumber]

So now in your page2 - you can pull in the [id] and [orderNumber] simply by using params, no need to import anything:

```
const OrderConfirmation = ({ params }: { params: { id: string, 
orderRef: string } }) => {
  return <div>My Params: {params.id} & {params.orderRef}</div>
}
export default OrderConfirmation;
```